# MVC2 login with Active Directory error=“Unable to establish secure connection with the server”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, active-directory

I got this strange error message:

> Unable to establish secure connection with the server

when I try to login with my AD account. I've tried to connect to LDAP in ASP.NET webforms and it seems to work fine there and I don't think its the connection string who cause the problem.

But when I'm using MVC, the parser error appears. I've also tried to look around and google it but I can't seem to find the right solution. According to configuration error it says that
the source error is:

```
<add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
     connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
     connectionUsername="cn=actualUser" 
     connectionPassword="actualUsersPassword" />`
```

Here is my `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://IPadress/DC=example,DC=test"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="15" 
             slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
             connectionUsername="cn=actualUser" connectionPassword="actualUsersPassword" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <pages>
       <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
       </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Here is my class, i got the error message from "  if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {" where it points to the membership provider in web.config :

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName,Convert.ToBoolean(model.Password));
            if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set your windows authentication mode to Windows ?

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: Still having the problem.. nobody?

Comment: Anymore info in the event logs?  Is this the same domain your machine is in that you are trying to connect to?  Have you checked w/ your Network Engineers for any permissions issues?

Comment: yes correct, it is the same domain. I am running windows server via virtual window(parallels desktop) and i have checked all the permissions issues that i can think of.

Comment: Still have the problem. The source i used is: http://ricardodsanchez.com/2012/04/18/how-to-secure-your-asp-net-mvc-application-and-use-active-directory-as-the-membership-provider/